UIButtons don't show
I have the following UIButtons
 // Create the left UIButton
    let leftButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    leftButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "thumbsup"), for: .normal) // Replace with your left button image name
    leftButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    // Create the right UIButton
    let rightButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    rightButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "thumbsdown"), for: .normal) // Replace with your right button image name
    rightButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    innerView.addSubview(leftButton)
    innerView.addSubview(rightButton)
    
    // Set constraints for the labels and buttons
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        
        // Constraints for the left button
        leftButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: innerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -20),
        leftButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: innerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 40),
        leftButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50), // Adjust the width as needed
        leftButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50), // Adjust the height as needed
        
        // Constraints for the right button
        rightButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: innerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -20),
        rightButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: innerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -40),
        rightButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50), // Adjust the width as needed
        rightButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50) // Adjust the height as needed
    ])

The problem is the left and right button don't show up when I run the simulator. Does anyone know why?

What are innerView's constraints?
